# Should I have my own mobile app for a [dot]app domain name?

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, google-domains

I plan to buy a `.app` domain name (e.g., `www.example.app`), however, I don't have a mobile app for that website. Is it really that important to have an app for a `.app` website?

This [get.app success stories](https://get.app/#success-stories) page on the `.app` Google Registry site lists websites that have their own mobile app, which is why I am asking. Is a mobile app really needed for a `www.example.app` website?

Answer (score 3):

The registry does not force you to have an application to register a `.APP` domain name. You can register one and do whatever you want with it, mobile application or not, the TLD is open.

The only thing that you need to take care of, and that should be displayed by your registrar before you buy the domain, is that you buy a certificate as otherwise your website will not work. Said otherwise, for .APP based websites, only https:// requests will work, and not http://

This is because Google added .APP, like its other TLDs (.PAGE, .DEV, .NEW, etc.) to the HSTS preloading list, which means that no browser will attempt an HTTP query to a website on those TLDs, there will only do HTTPS queries, and hence you need to have a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule about the usage of TLDs(other than .gov or .org).

But some are more obvious than others.

Like someone can use .com instead of .biz and it won't make a difference, but TLDs like .app is more of a "signature TLD". Anyone reading the domain www.xyz.app would assume that they would be redirected to a webpage which would prompt them to install an app which works if that's what you want your end-user to think.

But if it's otherwise, I don't think there is a benefit or harm for a .app TLD other than the fact that you could use it in the future when you develop an application.